# Parallel ForEach and ConcurrentBag

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I've got a `ConcurrentBag` exposed to read/write operations inside a `Parallel.ForEach`.  Basically, I need to check for the existence of the object in the bag based on several properties and if there's no match, then I add it to the bag.  It's really, really slow.  Using a `List<>` without a lock is a fraction of the time.  What's wrong with this code?  Am I better of using a list locking with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`?  I am processing about 1,000,000 objects here.

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<Beneficiary>();

Parallel.ForEach(cx, _options, line =>
{
if (!bag.Any(o =>
       o.WinID == beneficiary.WinID &&
       o.ProductType == beneficiary.ProductType &&
       o.FirstName == beneficiary.FirstName &&
       o.LastName == beneficiary.LastName &&
       o.MiddleName == beneficiary.MiddleName))
{
       bag.Add(beneficiary);    
}
}
```

Comment: The code's performance is irrelevant if it doesn't actually work correctly.  Do you want an incorrect result really quickly or a correct result more slowly?  Not that there aren't ways to improve this, it's just that "screw thread safety" isn't the way to go about it

Answer (score 3):

A `ConcurrentBag<T>` isn't optimized for this type of scenario.  It is implemented using `ThreadLocal<T>` which makes your particular use case slow.  You're iterating over the entire collection on many threads repeatedly.  Iterating over an entire collection to check for the existence of an object is also slow.

I would suggest overloading `Beneficiary.GetHashCode` and using a `ConcurrentDictionary<Beneficiary, byte>`.  The byte value can just be ignored and it's effectively a concurrent hashset.

Comment: You can also (using a ConcurrentDictionary) use a Tuple<> as key

Comment: @Seb How does that help?

Comment: What's the bag useful for?  What's the point of overloading GetHashCode?

Comment: @BigDaddy You need to override `GetHashCode` for `ConcurrentDictionary` to efficiently bucket items.  Ideally you want to minimize collisions (two different items with the same hash code).  You may also want to override `Beneficiary.Equals` if you don't want to do the default reference comparison when there's a hash collision.

Comment: @Servy by using a Tuple as Key you wont have to override and implement Beneficiary.GetHashCode

Comment: @Seb...Can you elaborate?  Maybe in an answer

Comment: Done ... I just posted an answer

Answer (score 3):

So first off, the solution that you have there isn't type safe at all.  Items can be added to the collection while you're iterating through the copy, or even after you perform the `Any` but before you call `Add`.  You're also doing a linear search, which isn't going to perform well at all.  You're better off both using a dictionary based structure which will have faster lookup, and you also need to make sure that the entire method you have here is logically atomic.

What you could do is use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and create an `IEqualityComparer` that checks the 5 properties that you care about, which will allow you to add the items to the dictionary while overwriting duplicates.

Of course, this is all only meaningful if creating each object actually takes a lot of work.  If all you're trying to do is get a collection of distinct items then it's likely that trying to parallelize that operation is just not going to be a win.  If that's basically all you're doing then the resources each thread needs to do its work are going to be in such contention that the amount of actual parallelization you'll have will be very low, almost certainly way less than the overhead of threading will cost you.  You'd likely be better off just using a synchronous `Distinct` call instead.

Comment: What's the purpose of the bag? What should it be used for?  BTW, this  is processing about 1,000,000 objects.  It looks like I need a dictionary.

Comment: @BigDaddy Yes, and I suggested that you use a hash-based data structure, namely `ConcurrentDictionary`, if you really needed to do this work in parallel.  As I said in my answer though, *the work that you're trying to do does not lend itself to parallel work*.  You're likely making it slower trying to parallelize it, so just don't.  It's not going to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Tuple` as key and use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to store your `benificiary` object.

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, object, string>, Beneficiary>();

Parallel.ForEach(cx, _options, line =>
{
    string fullname = string.Join("|", line.FirstName, line.LastName, line.MiddleName);

    Tuple<int, object, string> key = new Tuple<int,object,string>(line.WinID, line.ProductType, fullname);

    //if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) optional line
    {
        dict.TryAdd(key, line);}
    }
});
```

Once the `parallel.ForEach` is completed, you can access the distinct beneficiary using a simple `ForEach`.

Note:  you should replace the "object" type by the typeOf ProductType.

Comment: Why are you joining the names, instead of using `Tuple<int, ProductType, string, string, string>`?

Comment: Your solution is better and safer but I'm a bit lazy. I try to avoid tuples more than 3 elements as much as possible for readability. Key collision in that specific case is improbable so I took the liberty to join the fields. Regards.